# Integral convergence using Taylor expansion

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence, taylor-expansion, binomial-theorem

How can I analyze for which $s$ the integral $\int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^s} {\sqrt[3] {1+x^7} - 1} dx$ converges? I simplified $\sqrt[3] {1+x^7}$ using the binomial formula but I don't know how to continue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest is using *equivalents* near $0$:

By the binomial formula,  $\sqrt[3]{1+x^7}=1+\frac13 x^7+o(x^7)$, so the denominator is
$$\sqrt[3]{1+x^7}-1=1+\frac13 x^7+o(x^7)-1= \frac13 x^7+o(x^7),$$
which shows that $\sqrt[3]{1+x^7}-1\sim_0\frac13 x^7$, hence
$$\frac{x^s} {\sqrt[3] {1+x^7} - 1}\sim_0 3\mkern 1mu  x^{s-7},$$
and the latter converges if and only if $\;s-7>-1$.